# Using substring on string manipluation

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that has a string length of 66

Then I display it, using this one:

```
string.Substring(0, 20);
string.Substring(21, 40);
string.Substring(41, 60); --Error here
string.Substring(61, string.Length)
```

Why do I get an error saying that. Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: thatshould be 66. My bad

Comment: The second parameter should be the length. So, if you start from 41 and go up to 60 length, you will get an exception, Since your total string length should be at least 41+60

Answer (score 1):

well,

first argument for substring is the start position

second argument for substring is the **length**, not the end position

`41 + 60 = 101` => it's a little bit more than 66.

you should use

```
string.Substring(0, 20);
string.Substring(21, 20);
string.Substring(41, 20); 
string.Substring(61, 5);
```

Edit :

```
const int Length = 20;
var str = "myString";
var i = 0;
var list = new List<string>();
do {
  list.Add(str.Substring(i *Length, Math.Min(str.Length - (i*Length), Length)));
  i++;
}while (str.Length > i*Length);
```

Comment: I want to divide a strinng by 20 characters. No matter how long it is. So a long string will break down into series of string lines

Comment: So I should not use subtring if I want to divide it by atleast 20 characters

Comment: @ljpv14 see edit, you'll have the idea (use Math.Min to avoid exception in substring)

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus code will do exactly what your after, for strings of any length..

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in C#'s substring method is length, in the last two examples there are not that many characters left to take a substring of.